# How to extract .mp4 URLs from a tweet via the widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I can extract everything else, images, name, user, date posted, etc.. Just can't seem to extract an `.mp4` url. Anyone have an idea on this?

Currently how I am extracting images:

```
  function extractImageUrl(image_data) {
    if (image_data !== undefined && image_data.innerHTML.indexOf('data-srcset') >= 0) {
      var data_src = image_data.innerHTML
          .match(/data-srcset="([A-z0-9%_\.-]+)/i)[0];
      return decodeURIComponent(data_src).split('"')[1];
    }
  }
```

Comment: @SleekGeek whenever you post a `gif` in a tweet, twitter seems to convert them to `.mp4`. They reside in a `div` called "player-wrapper" Then within the wrapper, another `div` called "video-display" holds the actual `video src="etc..."></video>` **[here is an image to show you](http://imgur.com/Pe5lLhP)**

Comment: @SleekGeek Well it will be different based on the tweet, but this is kind of where they sit if you dive into them: https://pbs.twimg.com/tweet_video/CkS1eQMWUAArGtP.mp4

    Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: The link you gave me does not seem like it retains the src. it dissappears the moment it stops playing

Comment: @SleekGeek That's the correct link, it's set to `loop` via the `<video>` tag